# How to install GNU MP (GMP) in Codeblocks on Linux mint

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linux-mint, gmp

I was able to install GMP following a tutorial using MSYS2 in Windows, however I am quite unsure of how to do the same on Linux Mint. I can't use Windows as I need to use C++17, which MSYS2 doesn't let me do because my windows is outdated, so to use C++17 I use Linux. I am using a clang compiler, but I don't know how to install GMP to use with it on Codeblocks. https://gmplib.org/

Comment: You need `libgmp-dev`. Install as usual. As per below comment, you can do a `apt list | grep <name>` with linux mint.

Comment: I'm confident that you don't need to download or install `gmp` in Linux mint. Linux Mint is a large Linux distribution and gmp is a fairly popular library, so Linux mint must already have a pre-compiled package containing the gmp library and its development files that you can install. You just have to read Linux Mint's documentation on how to install its software packages, and search its package database for what you need to install. Linux is not Windows.

Comment: Ok I probably should have specified more, ```gmp``` is on Linux mint, however I can't use it I get ```undefined reference to __gmpz_init``` and I have (in my linker options) ```-lgmp```

Comment: Ok for some reason ```--purge remove codeblocks``` and reinstalling it fixed the problem, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `gmp` from [here](https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/).

```
wget https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz
unxz gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz
tar xzvf gmp-6.2.1.tar
cd gmp-6.2.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

it should be installed under `/usr/local/`.

The debian way: Enable the sources repositories under your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  then install `apt-src` to easily build the package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-src
apt-src update
apt-src install gmp
apt-src build gmp
```

Next step install the `*.deb` file through `apt`, `dpkg` or `gdebi`.

Why building `gmp`?: because only the source package is available on debian/ubuntu derivatives ([Source Package: gmp (2:6.1.2+dfsg-2)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/gmp) )

Comment: Why build it instead of installing a prebuilt package?